# insert and fetch strings and matrices to/from MySQL with Matlab

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I need to store data in a database. I have installed and configured a MySQL database (and an SQLite database) in Matlab. However I cannot store and retrieve anything other than scalar numeric values.

```
% create an empty database called test_data base with MySQL workbench.
% connect to it in Matlab
conn=database('test_database','root','XXXXXX','Vendor','MySQL');

% create a table to store values
create_test_table=['CREATE TABLE test_table (testID NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, test_string VARCHAR(255), test_vector BLOB, test_scalar NUMERIC)'];
curs=exec(conn,create_test_table)
```

Result is good so far (curs.Message is an empty string)

```
    % create a new record
    datainsert(conn,'test_table',{'testID','test_string','test_vector','test_scalar'},{1,'string1',[1,2],1})

% try to read out the new record
sqlquery='SELECT * FROM test_table8';
data_to_view=fetch(conn,sqlquery)
```

Result is bad:

```
data_to_view =

     1   NaN   NaN     1
```

From the documentation for "[fetch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fetch.html?s_tid=srchtitle)" I would expect:

```
data_to_view =
    1×4 table
         testID        test_string      test_vector    test_scalar    
      _____________    ___________    ______________    ________    
           1            'string1'       1x2 double         1
```

Until I learn how to read blobs I'd even be willing to accept:

```
data_to_view =
    1×4 table
         testID        test_string      test_vector    test_scalar    
      _____________    ___________    ______________    ________    
           1            'string1'           NaN             1
```

I get the same thing with an sqlite database. How can I store and then read out strings and blobs and why isn't the data returned in table format?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab does not document that the default options for SQLite and MySQL database retrieval are to attempt to return everything as a numeric array. One only needs this line:

```
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray')
```

or

```
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','table')
```

in order to get results with differing datatypes. However! now my result is:

```
    data_to_view =

      1×4 cell array

        {[2]}    {'string1'}    {11×1 int8}    {[1]}
```

If instead I input:

```
datainsert(conn,'test_table',{'testID','test_string','test_vector','test_scalar'},{1,'string1',typecast([1,2],'int8'),1})
```

Then I get:

```
data_to_view =

          1×4 cell array

            {[2]}    {'string1'}    {16×1 int8}    {[1]}
```

which I can convert like so:
typecast(data_to_view{3},'double')

ans =

```
 1     2
```

Unfortunately this does not work for SQLite. I get:

```
data_to_view =

          1×4 cell array

            {[2]}    {'string1'}    {'      �?       @'}    {[1]}
```

and I can't convert the third part correctly:

```
typecast(unicode2native(data_to_view{1,3}),'double')

ans =

    0.0001    2.0000
```

So I still need to learn how to read an SQLite blob in Matlab but that is a different question.